# Why am I seeing OPTION (MAXDOP 1) in my Actual query plan even though I've not set it in the stored proc?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, performance-testing, performance-tuning

SQL Server is set with `MAXDOP 0` by default. In the stored procedure I'm testing I keep seeing `WITH (MAXDOP 1)` in the Actual Execution Plans even though I've not specified any hints other than `SORT_IN_TEMPDB = 1`. The main Stored Procedure calls another procedure which grabs the table, generates scripts on each disabled index, then executes that series of scripts (with the afformentioned query hint). The funny thing is I'm seeing a high CPU cost for the operation so I imagine there's benefits to parallelism.

The table has a few million rows and is very wide.

Unfortunately, the database is file and TempDB file are on the same datastore and the TempDB is just 1 file as opposed to several. This configuration is out of my control but perhaps it's related to the reason for no parallelism.

The server is on a VM with 4 cores and 64 GB RAM.

Any thoughts on why SQL Server insists on dropping parallelism on such a large operation on a large table?

EDIT: Added script for the Inner stored procedure that gets called during Upserts:

`CREATE PROCEDURE etl_Index_EnableDisable`
`@DatabaseName NVARCHAR(50)`
`,@TableName NVARCHAR(50)`
`,@EnableDisable NVARCHAR(50)`

`AS`
`BEGIN`

```
 IF @DatabaseName IS NULL
   RAISERROR('Null values not allowed for @DatabaseName', 16, 1)
 IF @TableName IS NULL
   RAISERROR('Null values not allowed for @TableName', 16, 1)
 IF @EnableDisable IS NULL
   RAISERROR('Null values not allowed for @EnableDisable', 16, 1)

 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)

 -- Interpret 1 as enable and 0 as disable. Also set to Upper case
 SET @EnableDisable = CASE UPPER(@EnableDisable) WHEN '1' THEN 'ENABLE' 
                                                 WHEN 'REBUILD' THEN 'ENABLE' 
                                                 WHEN '0' THEN 'DISABLE' 
                                                 ELSE UPPER(@EnableDisable) 
                      END


 SET @SQL = ' DECLARE @SQLIn NVARCHAR(4000)  
              SELECT @SQLIn = COALESCE(@SQLIn,'' '') 
              +  SQL1 FROM ( (SELECT '' ALTER INDEX '' + si.name + '' ON ' + @DatabaseName + ' .dbo.'' + st.name + ' + CASE @EnableDisable WHEN 'DISABLE' THEN ''' DISABLE ''' 
                                                                                                                     WHEN 'ENABLE' THEN ''' REBUILD WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON) ''' END + '
                 AS SQL1
                  FROM ' + @DatabaseName + '.Sys.indexes si
                       JOIN  ' + @DatabaseName + '.Sys.tables st ON si.object_id = st.object_id
                  WHERE st.name = ''' + @TableName + '''
                        AND (si.is_unique = 0
                             AND si.is_unique = 0
                             AND si.is_primary_key = 0
                            AND si.[type] = 2
                            )
                       AND si.is_disabled = ' + CASE @EnableDisable WHEN 'DISABLE' THEN '0'
                                                                    WHEN 'ENABLE' THEN '1' 
                                                END + '
                       AND si.Name IS NOT NULL
               ) ) tb

             EXEC sp_sqlexec @SQLIn '

 EXEC sp_sqlexec @SQL
```

END`

Comment: Are you using resource governor?

Comment: What result returns following query: `SELECT * FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = 'max degree of parallelism'`

Comment: Is this an index rebuild? What edition are you on?

Comment: I suspect the other stored procedure that "generates scripts" generates dynamic SQL and adds this on as a hint?  Can you post the text of the stored procedures in question (obfuscated if required)?  `tempdb` config cannot inhibit parallelism.

Comment: @SlavaMurygin I get the following results from that query: value: 0, minimum: 0, maximum: 32767, value_in_use: 0, is_dynamic: 1, is_advanced: 1

Comment: @MartinSmith It's a rebuild. I'm using Standard edition

Comment: @wBob Added the Stored Procedure to my explanation.

Comment: @SeanGallardy No that is not enabled.

Comment: Thanks.  `sp_sqlexec` is deprecated.  Is it the original `sp_sqlexec` or has someone tinkered with it?  I suspect there is a logical explanation.  Can you show us the execution plan xml where you see `WITH (MAXDOP 1)`.  I was thinking plan guides is another possibility but it seems unlikely.

Comment: Parallel index rebuilds are enterprise edition only.

Comment: @wBob Thanks for the heads-up. I changed it to sp_executesql. It appears that since this server isn't enterprise SQL Server forces index rebuilds to be done in serial. See MartinSmith' comment and the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189329.aspx#Restrictions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are performing an index rebuild on Standard edition.

As documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) you would need Enterprise or Developer edition to see parallelism for this.